# Shellcode as payload for buffer overflow (or other) exploits executed as root?

Tags: security, buffer, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

When I use shellcode such as the ones provided [here](http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow5.html)<sup>*****</sup> as payload to some vulnerable program, how is the shell executed as root? I am asking about how the privileges are elevated to root? The shellcode doesn't seem to call `setuid` or anything to change user.

<sub>* http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow5.html</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those examples include the following:

```
     mov $70, %al           #setreuid is syscall 70
```

So they're using the `setreuid(2)` syscall, which sets both the real and effective user IDs of the process:

```
   int setreuid(uid_t ruid, uid_t euid);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute shellcode you need a vulnerability like a buffer overflow.   The shellcode has all of the rights as the running process.  So if you exploit a binary that is setuid root like the `passwd` command or otherwise running as root such as the `cupsd` daemon process then the attacker will have root access.   The kernel can also suffer from a buffer overflow,  and root access can be obtained this way as well.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to giving the program as root privileges (use chown and chmod as root). and you need setreuid() for your payload. that's would give you root, if you can exploit the program by other user.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if your vuln program has an owner `root` and your shellcode have a `setuid(0)` syscall, you can execute `/bin/sh` as `root`